# Why this question is on hold?

Tags: discussion

**UPDATE**: I have edited my question and have added more specific details.

I have posted [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/54976/what-information-to-share-and-what-to-hide) question today. It is on hold saying

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

I think this question is logical and is similar to many other questions like [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/54765/what-to-do-with-students-coming-to-office-hours-asking-to-check-their-homework) and [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/54874/how-to-explain-to-a-student-that-it-is-common-to-include-a-supervisor-as-a-co-au). I agree my question will have many answers , so do other questions I mentioned. What kind of specificity you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

There are simply so *many* types of information and so many different fields.  I would suggest narrowing your question to a specific field (e.g., "In theological studies, what types of information...") or a specific class of information (e.g., "When is it a good idea to share anonymized experimental subject databases?").

If you have multiple areas that you would like to ask about, you can ask multiple questions (though I would not suggest asking too many all at once---you will likely get better quality answers if you ask a few at a time).

Comment: I have edited original question, Check now!

Answer (score 0):

Your question also includes the statement:

> I know this will depend on kind of research you and your rivals are doing but still is there any commonality ?

which already indicates that the question is likely to be considered "too broad" (and indeed, the answer could vary greatly from field to field).

Comment: I have edited original question, Check now!

Answer (score 0):

Even with your edited question Dexter, it's going to be difficult if not impossible to answer. For example, does your work come from a specialized data set that would be hard to replicate? Is it work in progress, or near its final form? Is the manuscript ready for submission? Is your group powerful another that someone running off with a conference result of yours would blow back on them?

Comment: I think a general discussion of these principles from the perspective of the computational biology community is what the question is looking for.

Comment: @jakebeal The thing is, as someone who is...well, one field adjacent to computational biology, my first answer was "Ummm....."

Comment: I don't know, but I am feeling now you are being biased. Questions which I cited above are as subjective as mine. Why are they allowed then? Please delete my question instead putting on hold :/

Comment: I can't particularly see how I'm being "biased". You might disagree with me, but that means we disagree, not that we're being biased. Additionally, my concerns have nothing to do with subjectivity, but "How closely held should I keep my bioinformatics data" doesn't have enough detail in it to provide you a good answer.

Answer (score -10):

I think it might mean that there are moderators that want their peeps to answer the question rather than the general public.